# Embedded UICollectionView not getting didSelectItemAtIndexPath calls

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that is placed in a container view so that I can use a separate controller for it. The data loads and is displayed perfectly. BUT I don't get `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` calls, even though I made sure to set up the same controller to serve as data source and delegate. What drives me crazy is that I do get calls to `shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath` and `didHighlightItemAtIndexPath`. I also explicitly set `allowsSelection` and `allowsMultipleSelection` to YES. How is it even possible that I don't get selection functionality?
Wasted several hours on this, and would appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend you post your code.

Comment: @RegularExpression. I'm afraid there isn't really any substantial code to show, because everything was done in the storyboard. Apart from initializing my simple custom cells I was simply using NSLog in the various methods of UICollectionViewDelegate.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and it's definitely related to the container view. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Frank. Actually I did figure it out. Basically I had a tap gesture recognizer attached to the main view, and that was apparently intercepting the touches. Once I moved the recognizer to one of the subviews the embedded collection view started working perfectly.